# Best build target for ActionBarSherlock library?

Tags: actionbarsherlock

The docs on the ABS website seem slightly inconsistent.

On http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html it says
"Due to its use of the native action bar and its related classes on Ice Cream Sandwich, the library requires that both it and your project are compiled with Android 4.0 or newer."
This implies to me that it is okay to build both project and library with API 16.

However, on http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html it says "The library itself must be built against Android 4.0 (API level 14). Your project should be built using the latest version of the SDK as possible as long as it is 4.0 or newer."
This implies to me that API 16 is okay for the project, but the library should be built with API 14.

So, then, my question is, 16 or 14 for the library?

Thanks in advance, and thanks to Jake for writing and supporting ABS.

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is designed to make a decision on launch time:

1. Use the system's built-in ActionBar, etc. widgets and classes
2. Use ABS's compatibility ActionBar, etc. widgets and classes

It uses your build target to make that decision. If you target 4.0, then devices with 4.0 will use their built-in widgets and classes in your app. Devices with 4.1 and higher will do the same. Devices with any version below 4.0 (so, 3.2 and below) will use the compatibility ABS stuff.

Changing the target to 4.1 will make 4.0 use the compatibility ABS stuff, which is kind of unnecessary but not really harmful. But it's almost always better to just use what's on the device. So I'd recommend keeping it at 4.0.

Side note: 3.0 - 3.2 also have an ActionBar class, but it's missing a lot of features added in 4.0, so it's best to use ABS for those versions.